# What does Sally mean when she says "a Gap in the Long Earth"?

Tags: the-long-earth

In *The Long Earth*, when the protagonists first run into the Gap:

> "I don't think it was the stepping." Sally rubbed her own stomach. "It
>   was the weightlessness. And then the sudden return of gravity. It was
>   like falling."
>
> "Yeah. It really happened, didn't it?"
>
> "I think so," Sally said. "We found a gap. A Gap in the Long Earth."

Then, shortly after Lobsang appears,

> Sally was furious. "How did you manage to hit a vacuum *on Earth*?"
>
> Lobsang sighed. "Sally, we stepped into a place where there is no
>   Earth. A total vacuum, interplanetary space. ..."

When I reached the first quote, I read it to mean what Lobsang later confirmed, that the "Gap" is a missing Earth in the Long Earth. That's presumably why she said "Gap" in the first place. But her question to Lobsang makes me think she didn't think it was a missing Earth after all. Since she did say, specifically: "How did you manage to hit a vacuum *on Earth*?", with emphasis by the authors.

This feels like a discontinuity in the narration - as if Sally realised what had happened, named it the "Gap" with a capital G, and then immediately forgot what happened.

Comment: She does mean that they hit a point where there was no Earth only space.

Comment: The "Gap" is simply a stepwise world where the Earth is missing. In later books they site a space program there since the 'cost' of getting into orbit is zero dollars instead of billions.

Comment: @Valorum I haven't read the later books, but *I* understand what the Gap is. The question is, what does Sally mean when she first says it?

Comment: @Muru - She means what she says. How did they hit a vacuum on Earth. Lobsang tells her that they had unexpectedly gone into space.

Comment: @Valorum I think we're talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: @muru Sally says "I think so, We found a gap. A Gap in the Long Earth." meaning that they hit somewhere in the Long Earth where there was no Earth.

Comment: @Bellerophon yes, and then soon after she says "How did you manage to hit a vacuum *on Earth*?" as if she hadn't understood that they'd hit a missing Earth. Something's not adding up.

Comment: She knew they had hit a missing Earth but not how the Earth could be missing.

Comment: I'm towards the end of reading _The Long Earth_ and am pretty underwhelmed, there seem to be many plot holes :(